# Find a object from a list of objects in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to write plsql function , which takes employee_list(list of employee) and employee's name(varchar2 type) as parameter , then it iterates through list employees until it find a employee with corresponding name. Once the object is found function returns with employee's address.

> EMPLOYEE_OBJ Type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EMPLOYEE_OBJ AS OBJECT 
(name varchar2(1000), 
 address varchar2(1000)
);
```

> EMPLOYEE_OBJ_ARRAY Type(array of EMPLOYEE_OBJ)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EMPLOYEE_OBJ_ARRAY AS VARRAY(100) OF EMPLOYEE_OBJ;
```

> Function to get an object's value

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS (employee_list EMPLOYEE_OBJ_ARRAY,name varchar2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN 
FOR i in 1 .. employee_list.count LOOP 
      IF employee_list(i).name = name THEN
         return employee_list(i).address;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
RETURN NULL;
END;
```

ERROR that i am getting is:

```
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190100", line 590
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190100", line 576
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2033
```

Could you help me to fix this issue.
Also is there any simpler way to do this ? like select query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the provided `FUNCTION` appears to compile and execute fine on at least a couple versions of Oracle, there is a way to retrieve the address without iterating over the collection.  Below is an example, using the types you provided:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EMPLOYEE_OBJ AS OBJECT 
(name varchar2(1000), 
 address varchar2(1000)
);
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EMPLOYEE_OBJ_ARRAY AS VARRAY(100) OF EMPLOYEE_OBJ;
```

And the query:

```
SELECT ADDRESS FROM TABLE (EMPLOYEE_OBJ_ARRAY(
                      EMPLOYEE_OBJ('John','Finland'),
                      EMPLOYEE_OBJ('Molly','Spain')))
WHERE NAME = 'John';
```

Result:

```
   ADDRESS
__________
Finland


1 row selected.
```